# Making an Asynchronous WebService Call From ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-ajax, webmethod

I would (as the question states) like to make an asynchronous call, preferably using ASP.net AJAX.

The code for the WebMethod looks like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public void SendMail(string name, string email, string subject, string body)
{
  MailMessage toSend = new MailMessage(email, address@domain.com, subject, body);
  var smtp = new SmtpClient();
  smtp.Send(toSend);
}
```

The fields on the view are, not surprisingly: name, email, subject, body.

In my attempts to do this I haven't been able to get to the WebMethod. The service reference is in place, so at least I didn't screw that up.

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=314) you can find an example of invoking asynchronous methods with AJAX in ASP.NET MVC with elements like

```
<% using (Ajax.Form("SendMail", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "resultDiv" })) { %>

   <!-- Your form elements here... -->

<% } %>
```

You can receive the params in the controller method and call the webservice from there.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer to your question but a warning.  I was looking at this method and thinking, "hmm, I wonder if ASP.NET cares if a call to this web method comes from your site or somewhere else?"  A quick google search leads me to believe that there isn't any checking to make sure some douche isn't using your web methods for his own malicious desires ([here's a blog post talking about this](http://softwaredevscott.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!1A9E939F7373F3B7!484.entry)).

So, before you get this working, you might want to think about ways to prevent someone from hijacking your webmethod to send me Viagra emails.  Because if I get a Viagra email from your website, I'm not going to be very happy with you.

Comment: Hmmm, I hadn't considered that, thanks for the heads up. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I took a closer look at the link you put up. The call is not in the code behind for the page, but is in a .asmx file for a separate web service. I'll do some more reading to see if the same caveats apply.

Answer (score -3):

According to the MSDN Library

> In order for a Web service to be
>   accessed from script, it must be an
>   .asmx Web service whose Web service
>   class is qualified with the
>   ScriptServiceAttribute attribute.
>   Individual methods to be called from
>   script must be qualified with the
>   WebMethodAttribute attribute.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb398998.aspx

Comment: Well, the WebMethod attribute is right there and the scriptservice attribute is part of the class. So I'm not sure what you are trying to get to with this answer.